# Find the Area of the circle inscribed in a square.

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

**Objective**:To find **r** and area of the circle inscribed in a square, when two parameters are given.

Comment: *Hint* : Think of a very famous theorem about right triangles that might help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use Pythagorean Theorem : $r^2=(r-5)^2+(r-10)^2$[image]